# split string, set token and text view

Tags: java, android, string, view, split

I am writing a method, that will read a string, split a string, and then display one of the values in a text field. Here is what I have so far, it is compiling, but when the button is clicked, nothing is populated into the text field. Thanks

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

public class AboutScreen extends Activity{
  Button homeButton=null;
  Button getReactant1=null;
  TextView tv=null;
  String is=null;


@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.about);

  homeButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Home);
  homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();

  getReactant1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.combinationinterface);
  getReactant1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
      String string1 = getResources().getString(R.string.MgandO);
      String delims =",";
      String[] tokens = string1.split(delims);
      String i = null;
      tokens[0]= i;
      String f = null;
      tokens[1]= f;

      tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.R1TextInput);
      is=i; 
      tv.setText(i);
  }
  });
  }
  });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you called the `finish()` method at the beginning of the `onClick()`. Which stops your activity without doing the following stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is setting `OnClickListener` of `getReactant1` button inside of `homeButton`'s `OnClickListener`.

Your other problem is using irrelevant variables and not using splitted value at your textView.

Try to use and modify code below:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.about);

      homeButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Home);
      homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              finish();
          }
      });


      getReactant1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.combinationinterface);
      getReactant1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              String string1 = getResources().getString(R.string.MgandO);
              String delims =",";
              String[] tokens = string1.split(delims);
              String is=token[0];
              // or set it to another token you want i.e. token[1]

              tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.R1TextInput);
              tv.setText(is);
          }    
      });
  }
```